# Multivariable integration with change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable

If I would want to integrate the following

$$\int_1^2 \int_1^2\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \, dx \, dy$$

by doing a polar corrdinates change of variables $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$
I would get

$$\int_\text{?}^\text{?}\int_\text{?}^\text{?}\frac{r\cos\theta}{r^2} r \, dr \, d\theta $$

but what would be my bounderies then? I have trouble finding those bounderies to then integrate.

thank you for your help

Comment: Polar coordinates not needed. Hint: log or arctan.

Comment: I don't think polar coordinates are a good way to proceed here, because the bounds of integration are messy and would have to be defined piecewise.

Comment: I managed using log and arctan but I would like to know if using polar coordinates is also possible here or if not why so?

Comment: At least do first a translation of the origin in $(1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Per comment, polar coordinates are not a good way, but if you really would like to see as you mentioned:

Your area is a square and you need to divide it into two triangles.

For the lower triangle:

$$\theta \in (\arctan \frac{1}{2},\frac{\pi}{4})$$

$r$ is bounded by bottom and right line of the square:
$$\frac{1}{\sin \theta} <r < \frac{2}{\cos \theta}$$

Similar for the upper triangle, and I'll leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

To use polar coordinates for integrating over a square far from the origin is a bad idea. 
By Fubini's theorem

$$ \int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2}\log\left(\frac{4+y^2}{1+y^2}\right)\,dy = \int_{1}^{2}\left(\arctan\frac{2}{x}-\arctan\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx$$
and you may pick the one-variable integral you like the most and solve it by integration by parts.
For instance
$$ \int_{1}^{2}\arctan\frac{1}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{1}^{2}\arctan(x)\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}-\left[x\arctan x\right]_{1}^{2}+\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx $$
gives
$$ \int_{1}^{2}\arctan\frac{1}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}-[x\arctan x]_{1}^{2}+\frac{1}{2}[\log(1+x^2)]_{1}^{2}.$$
At last we have:
$$\boxed{ \iint_{[1,2]^2}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy = \color{red}{\arctan\frac{1}{3}+\log\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{5\sqrt{5}}}}$$
that is very close to one third.